# Extra interline spacing in two sided mode with scrlttr2, and tcolorbox environment redefining quoting environment

Tags: koma-script, tcolorbox, double-sided, quoting, scrlttr2

While experimenting with two sided settings in `scrlttr2` while using quoting in combination with `tcolorbox`, I came across an oddity. The following example shows interline spacing in text outside the quoting environment boxes. This only shows up in two sided mode, and only with `beforeafter skip=\baselineskip` in the `tcolorboxenvironment` invocation that redefines `quoting`. I'm puzzled what's causing this, since it's not obviously connected to anything about the quoting environment, or two sidedness.

```
%\documentclass[12pt, sections, headheight=30pt, headinclude, 
%firstfoot=false, enlargefirstpage=true, 
%foldmarks=false,foldmarks=blmtP, fromalign=center, fromphone, 
%fromemail, version=last, backaddress=false, subject=titled 
%{scrlttr2}

\documentclass[12pt, sections, headheight=30pt, headinclude, 
firstfoot=false, enlargefirstpage=true, 
foldmarks=false,foldmarks=blmtP, fromalign=center, fromphone, 
fromemail, version=last, backaddress=false, subject=titled, twoside] 
{scrlttr2}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\tcolorboxenvironment{quoting}{beforeafter skip=\baselineskip, boxrule=2pt, sharp corners, breakable, skin=enhanced, colback=white}
%\tcolorboxenvironment{quoting}{boxrule=2pt, sharp corners, breakable, skin=enhanced, colback=white}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\dummy}{m m m}
{
  \prg_replicate:nn { #3 }
  {
    \prg_replicate:nn { #2 } { #1 \hfill } \dummy_endline:
  }
}
\cs_new:Npn \dummy_endline:
{ { \parfillskip=0pt\par } }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Name}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Address}
\renewcommand{\phonename}{Landline}
\renewcommand{\mobilephonename}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{frommobilephone}{Mobile}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{Email}
\setkomavar{signature}{(\usekomavar{fromname})}
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}
\setkomavar{date}{\today}

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\centering
    \textbf{\jobname.tex} \input{"| hg log -v -l 1 \jobname.tex --template '{node}  {date|isodate}'"}
    \ifhmode \\ \fi
    {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont
      \hspace{\textwidth}
      \usekomavar{fromname}\\
      \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
      \usekomavar*{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{mobilephoneseparator}\usekomavar{frommobilephone}\\
      \usekomavar*{emailseparator}\usekomavar{emailseparator}\usekomavar{fromemail}
    }
  }%
}

\makeatletter
\@addtoplength{firstheadvpos}{30pt}
\@addtoplength{toaddrvpos}{40pt}
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{10pt}
\@addtoplength{sigbeforevskip}{20pt}
\makeatletter\@setplength{sigindent}{0.5\linewidth}\makeatother
\makeatother

\def\today{20th February, 2019}
\begin{letter}{
    Someone\\
    Company\\
    Building\\
    Street\\
    City
  }

  \opening{Hi}

  \dummy{HelloWorld!}{3}{5}
  \begin{quoting}
    \dummy{AlohaWorld!}{3}{3}
  \end{quoting}

  \dummy{BonjourWorld!}{3}{3}

  \begin{quoting}
    \begin{tabular}{p{4.5in}r}
      \textbf{\dummy{CiaoWorld!}{3}{1}  }  & \\
      \dummy{CiaoWorld!}{3}{2}             & \dummy{CiaoWorld!}{1}{1}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{quoting}

  \closing{Yours Sincerely,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

ADDENDUM: A hopefully simplified version which looks more like what I'm actually seeing.

```
\documentclass[12pt,sections,headheight=30pt,headinclude,firstfoot=false,enlargefirstpage=true,foldmarks=false,foldmarks=blmtP,fromalign=center,,version=last, backaddress=false, subject=titled, twoside=semi]{scrlttr2}

%\documentclass[12pt,sections,headheight=30pt,headinclude,firstfoot=false,enlargefirstpage=true,foldmarks=false,foldmarks=blmtP,fromalign=center,version=last, backaddress=false, subject=titled]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage{quoting}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}

\tcolorboxenvironment{quoting}{beforeafter skip=\baselineskip, boxrule=2pt,sharp corners,breakable,skin=enhanced,colback=white}

%\tcolorboxenvironment{quoting}{boxrule=2pt,sharp corners,breakable,skin=enhanced,colback=white}

\begin{document}
%\setkomavar{subject}{Subject Subject Subject Subject Subject Subject Subject Subject Subject Subject Subject  }
\setkomavar{subject}{Subject}

\makeatletter
\@addtoplength{firstheadvpos}{30pt}
\@addtoplength{toaddrvpos}{40pt}
\@addtoplength{refvpos}{10pt}
\@addtoplength{sigbeforevskip}{20pt}
\makeatletter\@setplength{sigindent}{0.5\linewidth}\makeatother
\makeatother

\begin{letter}{
    To Address
  }

  \opening{Hi,}

  Line 1.\\
  Line 2.\\
  Line 3.\\

  Line 1.\\
  Line 2.\\

  \begin{quoting}
    Line 1\\
    Line 2\\
  \end{quoting}
  Line 1\\
  Line 2\\
  \begin{quoting}
    Line 1\\
    Line 2\\
  \end{quoting}

\closing{Yours Sincerely,}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

The first page of the resulting 2 page file is shown below, which displays the problem

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When using twoside the class activates (like other classes often do) `\flushbottom`. That means that LaTeX will try to fill the page, and for this stretches the parskip.

The effect disappears if you remove the `beforeafter skip=\baselineskip,` as then the letter fits on one page.

In oneside mode you get the same if add `\flushbottom`.

To avoid the problem add `\raggedbottom`

Comment: Hi Ulrike. Thank you very much for the answer. Can you tell me where I should put `\raggedbottom` for this to work? And why is `\flushbottom` used in two sided mode, and not one sided mode? What is the logic?

Comment: Try it out - there aren't so many sensible places. And flushbottom is used traditionally in twoside mode, as there two pages can be seen side by side - simply open a book to see it.

Comment: I tried it in a couple of places, but it doesn't change anything. Where is the `\flushbottom` placed in the environment? And is there no way to simply switch that off?

Comment: Add \raggedbottom directly after \begin{document}.

Comment: Ok, I tried putting it just before the beginning of the last para on the first page, and that worked. But a fire-and-forget solution would be preferable. Directly after `\begin{document}` works, but is that a general solution?

Answer (score 1):

Using `\flushbottom` in twoside-mode was a bug in `scrlttr2` since version 3.17. It has been fixed in `scrlttr2` v3.27.3111 by adding `\raggedbottom` to the definition of the `letter` environment. Before this change

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{You\\There}
  \opening{Hi,}
  \blindtext\par\blindtext

  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{.5\textheight}

  \blindtext
  \closing{Bye}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

resulted in a warning message:

> `Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1`

and

[image: with KOMA-Script 3.26b]

With KOMA-Script 3.27.3111 (this is a [KOMA-Script pre-release](https://komascript.de/current)), it results in:

[image: from KOMA-Script 3.27.3111]

without warning message.

Note, there are additional [changes in upcoming KOMA-Script 3.27](https://komascript.de/node/2225) (linked page in German).

Comment: Hi, Schweinebacke, thank you for the answer. The version of KOMA I'm currently using is 2018/03/30 v3.25 (Debian pre-release of TeX LIve 2019). `2018.20190227-2` is available in Debian unstable. Would that version contain the KOMA version you mention? And do you concur that adding `\raggedbottom`directly after `\begin{document}` is the best workaround for now?

Comment: @FaheemMitha I do not know which version of KOMA-Script is in which version of a Debian package. But I do not think, that any distributor could have packaged on 2019-02-27 a KOMA-Script pre-release that has been made today after the bug has been recognized. And I would never expect (or recommend), that a distributor would package a KOMA-Script pre-release. You either have to wait for the release (and maybe several month until debian make an update) or use the pre-release from the location I gave in my answer.

Comment: Hi Schweinebacke. The fix was made today? Was this in response to my post, then? And if so, can you post a link to an issue, or a VCS diff, or something?

Comment: @FaheemMitha So, yes, currently with KOMA-Script v3.17–3.26b using `\raggedbottom` is the best workaround. Whether you place it after `\begin{documemt}` or use `\AtBeginLetter{\raggedbottom}` is your choice.

Comment: Well, I'm still using v3.25.

Comment: @FaheemMitha There is already a link to the German "[Geplante Änderungen in zukünftigen KOMA-Script-Versionen](https://komascript.de/node/2225)". The 3111 from the version information is the subversion release number. And there is a link [KOMA-Script via SF](https://sourceforge.net/projects/koma-script/) in the top menu of the [KOMA-Script Homepage](https://komascript.de). So you should be able to make your own diff. However, I would not try a single patch but either use a workaround or the official pre-release (see the link in my answer).

Comment: Thanks, Schweinebacke. It looks like this is the change from around 2 hours ago -  https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/code/3111/. I'll add a note to my question.